# azure-kubernetes-service fails at creation on webconsole

Tags: azure-aks

Im currently working on Azure and especially AKS.
In order to test the stack, i created a basic kubernetes cluster using web console on free account. RBAC is on.

Here my error : [[image: error[1]]

Comment: well, how did you create it specifically, whats the error? I'd suggest just recreating it

Comment: Where can i find the error ?

Comment: in the deployments, on the resource group